# Validar Input Type Date con variable php

Tags: php, html, date, entrada, db2

quiero implementar una variable dentro de mi input, es el siguiente:

```
<label class="titulo3">Fecha Desde:</label><br>
<input class="inpt"  align="center" required type="date" name="fecha" 
min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", time()) . "0 days")); ?>"  >
```

en el valor minimo, quisiera colocar una fecha, que tiene el siguiente formato= 
08/01/2019; guardado en una variable Php.

Como hago que mi fecha minima, sea validada con mi variable php

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta.

Comment: La "Fecha" la traes dinámicamente? con ese formato de dd/mm/aaaa separado por `/` no te va a funcionar, debe ser un formato de primero aaaa-mm-dd separado por guiones medios, te puedes apoyar en esta página [input Tipo date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date).

Comment: La fecha, la tengo en una variable, que lee la base de datos, y la guarda con ese formato, quiero implementarla en mi input, para que el valor mínimo sea esa, es decir! Necesito transformar mi variable, a un formato para que fucione implementandolo como "Min" en el input type Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En respuesta a tu comentario, suponiendo que tienes tu variable `$fecha` que tiene un valor d ela base de datos y la quieres pasar a una fecha que sea aceptada por el atributo `min=""` de **HTML**, podrías hacer algo así:

```
<?php 

$fecha = '08/01/2019';

$formatFecha = explode('/', $fecha);

$fechaA = $formatFecha[2].'-'.$formatFecha[1].'-'.$formatFecha[0];

?>
```

```html
<input type="date" min="<?php echo $fechaA;">
```

Answer (score 1):

viendo tu problemática, y tratando de entender un poco, creo que una opción sería: "descomponer" la `fecha` del `input` de manera de eliminar el `-` y lo regresarlo a una **variable** `$fecha_lim` en el formato que lo necesitas `dd/mm/aaaa`
y ya solo lo valido con el `if`.
espero sea de tu ayuda. Saludos

```
<?php
extract($_REQUEST);

echo "<form id='buscar' action='' method='get'>
    <h1>Buscar fecha</h1>
    <section>
        Fecha inicio: <input type='date' name='fecha_inicio' id='buscar' required><p>
    </section>
    <button type='submit' form='buscar'>Buscar</button>
</form>";

$fecha=list($anio,$mes,$dia) = explode('-', $fecha_inicio);

$fecha_lim = "$dia/$mes/$anio";

if ($fecha_lim == '08/03/2019') {
    echo "correcto";
}else
echo "incorrecto";

?>
```